# Combined UITableView with other elements - how to create and use the view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

Ive a project close to doing everything I need it to do.  Its got a Main page which has four buttons that allow you to choose an option.  Then a tableview page is launched from those options and displays a parsed XML feed from a website.  You can then select one of the options in the table to see a detail view of the item, enquire about it, etc.

My problem is I need to add more elements to the TableViewController page, other than the tableview itself.  I want a customized back button (not the navigation controller standard) plus some labels, images, etc.

In the TableViewController xib, the tableview itself fills the page.  I cant resize it to add more elements above it.  I can add a 'view' window seemingly above the tableview and put things in it.  But it seems to add the view to the tableview.  This means that when I scroll the table, the other elements like new back button, scroll away as part of the table.

So I'm led to wonder whether I need this page not to be a tableviewcontroller, but a viewcontroller, with a tableview inside it, as well as my other view with buttons, etc.  Is that the right way to go?  But if thats the case, then how do I instantiate the tableviewcontroller within code?  Because my page will not be of that type anymore - it will be just a viewcontroller.  But in code Im making a tableviewcontroller .. slightly scared by that route tbh.

Any illumination on this would be much appreciated, as various searches have left me none the wiser.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To customize it, this is the way to go:

- Change your class to be a view controller instead, which implements the TableViewDelegate and TableViewData Source protocols.
- In the view didLoad of you controller, create the table view, set its delegate, data source, and any other properties you wish and add it as a subview to your view.

  ```
  tableView = [[[UITableView alloc] init] autorelease];
  tableView.delegate = self;
  tableView.dataSource = self;
  // .. Other customization
  [self.view addSubview:tableView];
  ```

I suggest doing this programatically rather than IB.

Comment: ok got it, this sounds clear.  So once Ive changed the class to viewController, I'll be able to customize the page in the xib.  I add the tableview to this page, then instantiate in the viewDidLoad.  Sounds good, will give it a try.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a UITableViewController, you want a UIViewController that has an IBOutlet UITableView. Drag and drop a UITableView component from Storyboard and hook it up, and position it as needed on the screen. This UIViewController should implement the UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource methods.

Edit: Remember that a UITableViewController is just a subclass of UIViewController so you don't really have to get rid of all your code. :) You only need to make minor tweaks to your header and main file, and change the Storyboard to be a UIViewController instead of UITableViewController as I mentioned above.

Comment: ok thanks.  Im not using storyboards right now though, as Im stuck to supporting older versions of iOS.  But I get what you mean, will give it a try.